# Can I use a formula to find total opportunity value of years past in a workflow?

Tags: workflow, formula, date, custom-fiscal-year

I want to build a workflow around the following:

(Total $ value of opportunities in the current fiscal year > $1000
OR
Total $ value of opportunities in the past fiscal year > $1000
OR 
Total $ value of opportunities 2 fiscal years ago > $1000)
= TRUE

I have fields for FY17 opportunities, FY16 opportunities, etc., but I also want this workflow to work going forward without having to change the fields each year.

Is there a good way to do this via a formula? For example, can I somehow call the dollar value of current fiscal year? Alternatively, I am also okay with using calendar year instead of FY.

Comment: @SebastianKessel Account. I tried various forms of calling Opportunities for System.Today().year(), but with not much luck.

Comment: How are your fields `FY16` and `FY17` updating? Are they formula fields that are referencing current to calculate past years?

Comment: @Mahmood Rollup summary (Close Date GREATER OR EQUAL4/1/2016) AND (Close Date LESS OR EQUAL3/31/2017) AND (Stage EQUALS Posted)

Answer (score 2):

Relative date criteria do not work in Rollups - you would have to adjust the date filters every year.

Instead, you could try a tool like [Declarative Lookup Rollup Summaries](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries) or an app like Rollup Helper.

You could also look at using the [nonprofit success pack](http://www.salesforce.org/nonprofit/nonprofit-success-pack/), as it offers sophisticated rollup functionality that would allow you to calculate this information, but if you are just after the rollups I would start with DLRS or an app.  There is a [group for DLRS](https://success.salesforce.com/_ui/core/chatter/groups/GroupProfilePage?g=0F9300000009O5p) on the success community that might be a good place to start.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in one of the answers, [DLRS](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries) can be very useful, but in your case you can create a `Formula` field on Opportunity with a reference `date` field, something like

```
YEAR( [Reference date field] )
```

Lets call the above field `Creation Year` and then on your **Account** side, create a **rollup summary** field to summarize the Opp amount and apply filter criteria and check if the `Creation Date` field that you created above is `equal to current year`. This should calculate the all opp amounts of the current year, i.e. 2017. You can follow same steps to create two more rollup summary fields for last two years opp amounts as well.

Comment: Sounds interesting, but It's not possible to filter rollup summaries on formula fields, so how does this get around that?

Comment: Roll up summary will be on `amount` field, **filter criteria** will be on the formula field. And that you can do.

Comment: how do you filter that formula field is *equal to current year* without hard-coding the year?  while you can filter on formula field (as long as it doesnt contain relative date values like Today() or cross object field references), you cant use relative date filters in rollup summary filter criteria.